# AWK to get columns with non zero values

Tags: awk, grep, gawk

Any better idea to get columns / fields having non zero values.

Data

```
      col1 col2 col3 .... col50
      1      0   1         1
```

so output should be

```
    col1  col3 .... col50
    1       1         1
```

Edit: Example was wrong, so edited it.

Comment: What have you tried?  You're going to need to read all the data and the ability to check that all the values in each column for each row except the header row contains at least one non-zero value.  You can't start printing anything except the header line until you've read all the lines of data.  That makes it a problem for Awk.

Comment: Jonathan, actually example that i had was wrong, edit it now. Thanks for pointing out it.

Comment: Is the input file really just two lines, one header line and one data line?  Or do you need to just print the non-zero elements of each row except the first?  Or do you need to print the relevant heading and the relevant columns for each line (so you have output line 1 as a subset of headings, line 2 as the non-zero data in row 1, line 3 as a subset of the headings, line 4 as the non-zero data in row 2, etc)?  Or what?  And if it is simpler than it originally seemed to be, what have you tried once more?  But you really need to explain the input and output more clearly.

Comment: File having One header line, one data line.

Comment: OK — 1 line headings, 1 line data makes it nice and simple.  What's the problem doing it?  What have you tried?

Comment: Jonathan, i know this can be done with awk but not know exact command or pipes to apply for this. A quick help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

this should handle multiple rows as well...

```
$ awk 'NR==1{split($0,h); next} 
     NR==FNR{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i!=0) cols[i]; next}              
            {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if(i in cols) printf "%s", $i OFS; 
             print ""}' file{,} | column -t

col1  col3  col50
1     1     1
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk, more generic solution for multiple records. On the first go it checks for cols with 1s, on the second it outputs records with 1s:

```
$ cat program.awk 
NR>1 && NR==FNR {                             # find columns to output, build a arr on 1
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if($i) a[i]
    next
} 
sub(/1/,"1") {                                # output only records with 1s
    split($0,b," ")                           # split record to b arr
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
    if(i in a)                                # print on a arr
        printf "%s%s", b[i], (i==NF?ORS:OFS)
}
```

Data:

```
$ cat data.txt
col1 col2 col3 col4
0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
0 0 1 1
```

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk data.txt data.txt
col1 col3 col4
1 1 0
0 1 1
```